# How would I go about crediting another project who uses the MIT licence, in my project for which I also use the MIT licence

Tags: mit

I found [an implementation of the RIPEMD160 algorithm on GitHub](https://github.com/nayuki/Bitcoin-Cryptography-Library/blob/master/java/io/nayuki/bitcoin/crypto/Ripemd160.java), which I followed when writing my own implementation. Hence, I personally would consider my work to be a modification/derivative of this original. That code is a part of a project which is licenced under MIT:

> Copyright © 2019 Project Nayuki. (MIT License)
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> - The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
> - The Software is provided "as is", without warranty of any kind, express or implied, including but not limited to the warranties of merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose and noninfringement. In no event shall the authors or copyright holders be liable for any claim, damages or other liability, whether in an action of contract, tort or otherwise, arising from, out of or in connection with the Software or the use or other dealings in the Software.

I ALSO want to publish my code under the MIT licence, and attribute the above-mentioned project. How do I go about doing that in a neat way? What would the licence file look like? Anything I need to add to README.md? Do I have to include anything in the source code files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the appropriate way to include third-party libraries copyright notice and permission notice in my project source code?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7307/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-include-third-party-libraries-copyright-notice-an)

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT while I agree that the questions are similar (and potentially can be answered in one answer), the current answers IMHO are somewhat too brief to be a good answer to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are building upon MIT-licensed code and retaining the same license, I recommend writing it like this:

> **Copyright © 2023 Bob Foobar**
> **Copyright © 2020 Alice Margatroid**
> Copyright © 2019 Project Nayuki
>
> (MIT License)
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> - The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
> - The Software is provided "as is", without warranty of any kind, express or implied, including but not limited to the warranties of merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose and noninfringement. In no event shall the authors or copyright holders be liable for any claim, damages or other liability, whether in an action of contract, tort or otherwise, arising from, out of or in connection with the Software or the use or other dealings in the Software.